# Updating SQL 'WHERE' based on JSON AJAX checkbox selection

Tags: php, sql, ajax, checkbox

I have an AJAX HTML page and a submit PHP page, which sends data from SQL to update HTML on page.

I have a list of films within a PHPMyAdmin MariaDB table. One of the columns is "channel". Channel will either say "NOWTV", "BBC", or "SKYTV". I want the user to be able to select the channel and for this to update.

If I check the array for 1 string - for example: skytv, the SQL pulls the data. However, if I want to change the WHERE clause, based on selection - the filtering does not work.

I've tried ".=where OR" to change the channel selection.

ajax.html

```
<html>
<style>
body {
padding: 10px;
  }
h2 {
margin: 1em 0 0.3em 0;
color: #343434;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 40px;
font-fnuamily: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
}
#employees {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
background: #fff;
margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
#employees th {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #039;
padding: 4px 4px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #6678b1;
}
#employees td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
color: #669;
padding: 8px 10px;
}
#employees tbody tr:hover td {
color: #009;
}

.slidecontainer {
width: 50%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
appearance: none;
width: 50%; /* Full-width */
height: 25px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
-webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
appearance: none;
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #000000; /* Square background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="nowtv" name="nowtv" >
<label for="nowtv">Now TV</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="skytv" name="skytv" >
<label for="skytv">Sky Movies</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="iplayer" name="iplayer" >
<label for="iplayer">BBC iPlayer</label>
</div>

<h2>Max Run-Time:</h2>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" class="slider" id="runtime">
<p>Runtime: <span id="runtime_"></span></p>
</div>


<table id="employees">

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("runtime");
var output = document.getElementById("runtime_");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
/script>
  </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<p id="record_count"></p>

<script>
function makeTable(data){
var tbl_body = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
var tbl_row = "";
var t = i;
for (var j=0; j<4; j++)
{
//tbl_row +=("<td>" + data[i].tmdbid + "</td>");
tbl_row +=("<td><a href='new/" + data[i].tmdbid + "'><IMG SRC='webaddress"+ data[i].poster +"'></a></td>");
i++;
}
tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>" 
}
return tbl_body;
}
function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
var opts = {
checkboxes: [],
sliderValue: null
};
$checkboxes.each(function(){
if(this.checked){
opts.checkboxes.push(this.name);
}
});
var slider = document.getElementById("runtime");
opts.sliderValue = slider.value;
return opts;
}
function updateEmployees(opts){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "submit.php",
dataType : 'json',
cache: false,
data: opts,
success: function(records){
console.log(records);
$('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
}
});
}

var $checkboxes = $("input");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
updateEmployees(opts);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
'mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx'
);

$checkboxes = $_POST["checkboxes"];
$slider_value = $_POST["sliderValue"];
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM streaming';
$where = ' WHERE poster <>"" AND runtime <'  . $slider_value . ' AND channel = "X" ';
if (in_array("nowtv", $checkboxes))
{
$where .= ' OR channel = "NOWTV" ';
}
if (in_array("skytv", $checkboxes))
{
$where .= ' OR channel = "SKYTV" '; 
}
if (in_array("iplayer", $checkboxes))
{
$where .= ' OR channel = "BBC" '; 
}
$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
>
```

The output I am expecting is for the user to be able to select the checkboxes and runtime - to then update the films available.

The current output shows nothing. :(

Comment: aside from Nick's previous answer (which is clarifying sql statement with correct parethensis grouping), take note you're preparing the statement, but using it incorrectly `"" AND runtime <'  . $slider_value . ' AN`. don't inject the slider value directly into the query, use a question mark placeholder and bind the value instead

Comment: I can't see Nick's answer/support anymore? Seems to have gone?

Comment: @Ghost - unsure how to fix this?

Comment: he took it down, his answer basically covers the where clause grouping, the poster column is fine, the slider value needs to be bound, and lastly the channels needs to be on a separate grouping. ala `AND (channel = "X" or channel = "whatever")` and so on

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. OK.
How do I bind the slider value? Sorry.
For the where:
In the SQL statement, the grouping will be open in the original SQL setting:
$where = ' WHERE poster <>"" AND runtime <'  . $slider_value . ' AND (channel = "X" '

Until checkbox is ticked:
if (in_array("nowtv", $checkboxes))
  {
  $where .= ' OR channel = "NOWTV") ';
  }

What if there is no checkbox that is ticked?

Comment: just use questionmark placeholders `runtime < ?`, the use `$stmt->execute([$slider_value])`, i don't see any trouble if the user didn't check any box, just make sure the closing is added `$where .= ')'` at the end.

Comment: So:
$where = ' WHERE poster <>"" AND runtime <'  . $slider_value . ' AND (channel = "X" ';

Becomes:

$where = ' WHERE poster <>"" AND runtime <'  <?$stmt->execute([$slider_value])?> ' AND (channel = "X" ';

Is this correct?

Comment: What happens if the user clicks two checkboxes? Eg NOWTV and SKYTV?
Would the SQL say (channel  = 'X'  OR channel = 'skytv') OR channel = 'nowtv');